# Issues with Mac OS X's resource fork file "._uf029" for usage of .VolumeIcon.icns

Tags: macos, unicode, resources, fork, volume

There are a lot of guides out there on creating custom icons, but the challenge I have experienced is how to put .VolumeIcon.icns on some sort of mass produced volume (like a flash drive) so that all Macs after 10.4 use it.

OS X consistently creates something called a resource fork file for .VolumeIcon.icns which tells future Macs its mounted on to use it. This file, when I produced it on various Macs, has consistently been ._ follow by the special use character "uf029" in its filename - and this is where the problem lies. This file, therefore, shows up on Windows as ._? on OSX as . _ . (without the spaces, I'm guessing stackoverflow needs an escape char) and various other ways in different places. This file is required for .VolumeIcon.icns to work, it is always 4k, and seems to be composed of some proprietary encoding.

This is a vary hard file to manage, but I got around this on git by first zipping it - otherwise it isn't even recognized as a file (even though you can list it in a dir with ls -a, ls [filename] returns some variation of a file not found error, since its a resource fork file). More on that [here](http://www.whoopis.com/howtos/rsync-hfs-howto/).

I'm wondering how Ipods, for example, I've plugged in tell OS X to use the .VolumeIcon.icns file without this resource fork file (I see no ._. file when I ls -a the Ipod). How do other people distribute Volumes with a VolumeIcon to Mac users without this problematic file? Another way is to set a VolumeIcon attribute using the OS X dev tool "SetFile -a C /Volumes/name"

Any Apple developers out there know of a work around?